# How can I make this astronaut's oxygen tube collide with the astronaut?

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

Okay, so I got these two rigs I made in blender. One is a rig hooked up to empties and a set of vertices so that the rig will react to gravity. The other is a rig for the character herself, I named her Myrtle on another note. So I rigged her and the rigs work fine in fact better than I expected, the main issue is the helmet and backpack have a oxygen tube running between them that is reactive to gravity but I can't figure out how to make the tubing's mesh stop before clipping into her arm or body.This is before I run the simulation: [image: Myrtle the Astronaut]

And this is when I push play: 
[image: Air tube disrespecting mesh of character]